# string is recognized as object by strtolower function

Tags: php, string, function, object

The follow error I get when I try to [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) my string:

```
Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
```

When I do a `var_dump()` it shows me the string should be a string?

```
string(21) "This IS a Test String"
```

Some code:

```
protected $hostname;

public function __construct($hostname)
{
    //$this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->hostname = 'This IS a TeSt String';
    return $this->_filter();
}

private function _filter()
{
    $hostname = $this->hostname;
    var_dump($hostname);
    $hostname = strtolower($hostname);
    $hostname = $this->_getDomain($hostname);
    $hostname = $this->_stripDomain($hostname);

    return $hostname;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's strange! What happens if you attempt to typecast it? $hostname = strtolower((string) $hostname);

Comment: is this all the code? does the warning line correspond to the strtolower from `_filter` function?

Comment: It make no sense, I tried this already. Thanks!

Comment: Merci, shame one my eyes :$

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably caused by the fact that you are trying to `return` something from the constructor. You cannot do that.

You should try if this solves the problem:

```
public function __construct($hostname)
{
    $this->hostname = $hostname;
    $this->_filter();
}
```

Also, you seem to be doing a lot of duplicate assigning, so I would change your function to:

```
private function _filter()
{
    var_dump($this->hostname);
    $this->hostname = strtolower($this->hostname);
    // here you might need other variable names, hard to tell without seeing the functions
    $this->hostname = $this->_getDomain();
    $this->hostname = $this->_stripDomain();
}
```

Note that `$this->hostname` is available to all functions in your class, so you don't need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: lol we came to the same answer near enough just you beat me by like 30 seconds have a +rep :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work ok adjusted a little
I think you were overwriting variables back with the intial input

```
<?php 
class Test {
    public $outputhost;
    public function __construct($inputhost)
    {
        $this->hostname = $inputhost;
        $this->outputhost = $this->_filter();
    }
    private function _filter()
    {
        var_dump($this->hostname);
        $outputhost = strtolower($this->hostname);
        return $outputhost;
    }
}

$newTest = new Test("WWW.FCSOFTWARE.CO.UK");
echo $newTest->outputhost;
?>
```